# getting a query output to be a link(to another page)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a query to suck data from my database and return them(rows of user names) as links to their pages(respectively).

The query seeems to work but I am having some hard time echoing the link properly (I am probably missing '.' or something alog the line).

I would be greatful if someone could point me to my problem and why I get an error that the browser doesn't expect: `</a><br>`.

here is the code of the php page(on my html page i just stick the expected results so no need to show the logic there unless you would ask me to):

```
<?php
include('connectDB.php');

if( isset( $_POST['user_name'] ) )
{

$name = $_POST['user_name'];


    $query = $conn->query("SELECT U.firstName,U.lastName FROM tblfriendswith FW inner join tbluser U on U.userName=FW.userName2   WHERE userName1 LIKE '$name%' ");

    while($row = $query->fetch_row())
  {
    echo '<a href=\'userPage.php?fullName='. $row[0] .' '. $row[1].'>'.$row[0] .' '. $row[1].'\'>' '</a>''<br>';

  }
 }
?>
```

I tried to add a '.' between the  and the 
 with '' between and to no avail.

Thank you!
Tom

Comment: Submit result of while loop (you can pase just 1 URI generated), so we would point you, where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is with your echo...

```
echo '<a href="/userPage.php?fullName=', urlencode($row[0] . ' ' . $row[1]), '">', $row[0], ' ', $row[1], '</a><br>';
```

You must [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the query of the href parameter in your anchor tag as spaces and other funny characters may break your link.

In my example I've shown the echo statement with multiple inputs separated by commas (,). Echo takes a nearly unlimited number of input variables and will echo them out to the screen one after another. This method is much faster than concatenating the strings together with periods (.) before echoing and it may make your code easier for you to read in the future.